# Is it possible to double-alternate with nth-child?

Tags: css

I have multiple elements displaying floated left to create rows of 4 elements. I have made them alternate background colour:

```css
div > div { float:left; width:25%; height:50px; background-color:black; }
div > div:nth-child(2n) { background-color:white; }
```

```html
<div>
  <div id="el1"></div>
  <div id="el2"></div>
  <div id="el3"></div>
  <div id="el4"></div>
  <div id="el5"></div>
  <div id="el6"></div>
  <div id="el7"></div>
  <div id="el8"></div>
  <div id="el9"></div>
  <div id="el10"></div>
  <div id="el11"></div>
  <div id="el12"></div>
</div>
```

However, what I really need is to alternate between *black-white-black-white* and *white-black-white-black* to create a chess board effect. I don't want to alter the HTML if possible. So what I really need is way of alternating an alternate every 4 elements.

Comment: Please make a snippet so we can se what you want

Comment: @MrBuggy: If they could make a snippet showing what they want, they wouldn't need to ask this question.

Comment: @MrBuggy Done, but obv only showing what I've GOT, not what I want

Comment: You could do it like this https://jsfiddle.net/vs6dadgk/7/

Comment: This is how I would solve it: https://codepen.io/STWebtastic/pen/XEwqKV

Comment: @NenadVracar That's perfect - are you going to add it as an answer?

Comment: Question is closed.

Answer (score 0):

Simply move your selector to one before `2n` -> `2n-1`

```css
.board {
  width: 90px;
}

.board div {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
}

div > div { float:left; width:25%; background-color:black; }
div > div:nth-child(2n-1) { background-color:white; }
```

```html
<div class="board">
  <div id="el1"></div>
  <div id="el2"></div>
  <div id="el3"></div>
  <div id="el4"></div>
  <div id="el5"></div>
  <div id="el6"></div>
  <div id="el7"></div>
  <div id="el8"></div>
  <div id="el9"></div>
  <div id="el10"></div>
  <div id="el11"></div>
  <div id="el12"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is great for odd numbers of elements per row but unfortunately this won't work with even elements wide - after the fourth black I need another black